# Replace text in pdf by command line

Tags: pdf, command, pdf-generation, pdfbox, jspdf

I want to replace a `word` with `another word` by command line .
I search on google but only see paid solution by application .
Is there a free solution for that ?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.